# Is that possible to upload photos to Facebook album via an Android app

Tags: android, facebook, photo

I'm developing an Android app which's relevant to the users photos uploaded to Facebook, I'm wondering:
**1. Is that possible to upload photos to Facebook album instead of my own server;
2. If it's possible, can my app create a special album on Facebook?**
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**That is why Facebook SDK Available brotha.. Read the official Document below**

with that you can do whatever you want in which they provide

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

[This is the Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/)

Comment: Thank you for the tips, now I got it, it's not possible, I have to have my own server to save the photos which are uploaded by users via my app instead of Facebook